# Unity: refresh just one script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that is editing another script at runtime. I am currently using

```
AssetDatabase.Refresh();
```

to reload it, but then everything reloads and errors occur. Is there any other way to just reload the one script?

Comment: Can you share error messages.

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for but not sure this will ever work in a build. You should look into taking a different approach to your problem.

Comment: `AssetDatabase.Refresh` is only available within the Unity editor itself and won't be available in a build if that is your goal. What kind of errors occur? I would guess some related to your entire code being reloaded during runtime (something you shouldn't do in general not even in the editor since it e.g. also resets anything `static`) .. what exactly is your usecases?

Comment: I am working on a system, where you can write code inside the game. My solution currently is to edit/create a script with File.WriteAllLines(...). But when testing, it takes always a long time to compile and I get errors like: "NullReferenceException: Do not create your own module instances, get them from a ParticleSystem instance" . I probably need to change my entire solution. Any ideas how to bypass AssetDatabase.Refresh ()?

Comment: You need external solution to do that, probably not possible with just unity editor. Python code with ironpython, for example, though I'm not familiar with it so can't be sure.